# posting to .php downloads instead of showing up

Tags: php, html, post

Ok i'm new to php.Here is what i'm trying to do.
Here is my index.html

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
          Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
          Age: <input type="text" name="age">
          <input type="submit">
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm posting to `welcome.php`

```
<html>
   <body>
      Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br>
      You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.
   </body>
</html>
```

But instead of showing up the page, it downloads welcome.php

Comment: your webserver is not running , please start apache or nginx whatever you are running , or if it running , it has not been configured to handle php . pl check

Comment: So when you go to `welcome.php` it shows the source of the file, not rendered HTML? Check your server is configured to run PHP.

Comment: If you don't have any webserver at all and you want it the very simple way, take a look at XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Comment: Danger: You are vulnerable to [cross site scripting attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the server has PHP installed. If you have PHP installed, try restarting your server.

Comment: This is a comment not an Answer!

Comment: I cannot comment. It says I need 50 reputation. How to contribute to the website when I can only 'answer', and when I do I get min'ed?

Comment: @Ankit actually... THIS IS THE ANSWER. Reread the question please. The OP obviously DOESN'T have Apache or nginx running

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu/Linux you can install via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

**More:** https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that PHP is enabled on your server.

**If it is not enabled:** check the documentation that came with your server software.

**If PHP is not supported with your software:** You should download software similar to [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

WAMP is an Apache server combined with Mysql and PHP for the Windows operating system

(**W**indows-**A**pache-**M**ysql-**P**HP)